# Banner Images when deleted to not repeat number

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, image

I'm doing a banner with changing images.

When i delete a file form my images folder. When you delete an image, that number is deleted. When a new file is uploaded, it is given the number of one more than the total of current banners. There is a major problem with this, e.g. if we have four banners: 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg and 4.jpg. If we delete 2.jpg, we are left with 1.jpg, 3.jpg and 4.jpg. If we then uploaded a new image, the page would count the number of images (in this case three) and add 1, giving us a new file name of "4.jpg". We already have a file called 4.jpg, therefore, the old 4.jpg would be replaced.

How do I stop this from happening? This is the code for the banner.

```
      <?php
          confirm_is_admin();   

    $dir = 'Images/banner';
    $confirmation = "";

    if(isset($_GET["del"])){
        if (file_exists($dir . "/" . $_GET["del"])) {
            unlink($dir . "/" . $_GET["del"]);
            $confirmation = $_GET["del"] . " deleted. <br><br>";
        } else {
            $confirmation = $_GET["del"] . " doesn't exist. <br><br>";
        }
    }

    $files = scandir($dir);
    array_shift($files);
    array_shift($files);

    $newImage = COUNT($files)+1;

    if(isset($_GET["add"])) {
        $confirmation = "Image successfully uploaded.";
    }

    if(isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);

        if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
        && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 50 * 1024 * 1024) //50mb (1024 * 1kb = 1mb, 50 x 1024kb = 50mb)
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
          if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
          } else {
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
            echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $dir . "/" . $newImage . "." . $extension);
            echo "Stored in: " . $dir . "/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            header("Location: editBanner.php?add=1");
          }
        } else {
          echo "Invalid file";
        }
    }
 ?>


<div id="container">
    <div id="admin">
        <?php
            if(!empty($confirmation)) {
                echo "<div id='confirmation'>" . $confirmation . "</div>";
            }

            for ($i = 0; $i < COUNT($files); $i++) {
                echo '<div id="bannerImage">';
                echo $files[$i] . ' - <a href="editBanner.php?del=' .        $files[$i] . '">Delete</a><br>';
                echo '<img src="' . $dir . '/' . $files[$i] . '" width="200px" height="100px" /><br>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        ?>
        <div id="bannerAdd">
            <form action="editBanner.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <h3>Upload a New Banner Image</h3>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe you will have to check if each file exists or read the folder and propagate your list from what is there. It should be easy to sort them - I might explode the names like you did then place each file name (the number) into the respective index in an array and fill in the blanks with the new files.

Comment: To avoid a future StackOverflow question of the type "Why are my admin users eraseing files on my file system?", please don't use unchecked user input to delete files as you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to save the last number in a textfile or db. It won't work right with counting the files - after deleting some files you will get always "used" numbers.
After uploading a file get the current number from textfile or db and increase. Or: sort all files in that folder, put all filenames in an array, sort the array, get the highest number and increase.